# Default browser action takes place when using return false

Tags: javascript, popup

Please have a look at the code below:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/" target="awindow" id="" class="" onclick="javascript:open('some=;variables=;');return false;">
    <img src="" alt="" border="0" />
</a>
```

Is there something wrong in the syntax? Because it opens in a new tab instead of a popup and throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Open is a function that takes care of the popup, the variables between the brackets get added. It's a third party function, and has nothing to do with the     window.open functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you going to post the code for your open function?

Comment: You don't need the "javascript:" prefix in an "onfoo" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
// Remove uneeded "javascript:".
// open() is a function of window
onclick="window.open('some=;variables=;');return false;"
```

See [`window.open()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open).

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't quite clear about that open function, it's a function I made myself.

Comment: @Boyye, you're right, you weren't clear :). Post the code to your function. A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the issue would be helpful.

Comment: I can't post the code since it's a third party solution of which I'm sure there aren't any bugs in it. It must have something to do with the syntax behind the "open"-part.

Comment: @Boyye, you're incorrect. There is next to nothing going on in the click handler. The issue is likely with the open function. Even if it's a syntax issue, we can't help debug it until we know what the function is expecting. Unfortunately, if you can't post the code, I believe this question will be closed.

Comment: Okay, no problem, thanks for looking anyway.